# Jquery tab re-addition

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am trying to add undo/redo functionality in Jquery tabs. I am able to store and restore li/divs for added/removed tab.

Issue is when I re-add tab to the form, though it is added properly as li and div for that particular tab are present and can be seen. But if I click on that tab 'tabsselect' event is not getting fired. Li and div for tab look in order. But I am not able to figure what is missing.

In my website I am dynamically adding and removing tabs and it is working fine but just readding of once removed tab isnt working

Here is the code for adding tab

```
 var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
                    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span id='id1' class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
                    add: function (event, ui) {
                        var tab_content = $tab_content_input.val(); // || "Tab " + tab_counter + " content.";

                    }
                });
```

Here is the removal code

```
$("#tabs span.ui-icon-close").live("click", function () {
                    if (imode == 1) {
                        var index = $("li", $tabs).index($(this).parent());
                        if ($tabs.tabs("length") > 1) {
                           $tabs.tabs("remove", index);
                           }
                    }
                });
```

Nothing fancy really. Looking for answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This code out this will give you a nice example to manipulate data in tabs using jquery.

**JavaScript**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){   
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

var $a = $('<a />').appendTo('body').attr('href','#').html('add new tab').click(function(){
  var n = parseInt($tabs.tabs( "length" ),10)+1;
      $('body').append('<div id="tabs-'+n+'">content for the tab # '+ n +'</div>');

        $tabs.tabs("add",'#tabs-'+n,'Tab #'+n);
  return false;

});

    $('<a/>').html('<br><br>remove tab').attr('href','#').click(function(){

      $tabs.tabs('remove',$tabs.tabs('length')-1);
      return false;
    }).appendTo('body');

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab 1 content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Tab 2 content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Tab 3 content</p>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*
Just use the id's of the selected tabs and manipulate data in them. this will allow to add and remove tabs on your page
*

**Tab Select Function**

```
$('.ui-tabs-nav').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
     ui.options // options used to intialize this widget
     ui.tab // anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
     ui.panel // element, that contains the contents of the selected (clicked) tab
     ui.index // zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab
 });
```

Use ui.index to get the index of the selected tab and then add then manipulate the selected tab .

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rishabh but I am able to add/remove tab dynamically. Even undo/redo is working fine. My issue is that tabsselect is not getting fired for readded tab. So I am not able to select that tab. Once I save that page and reload it. It start selecting tab correctly.

Comment: Added the tabsselect function to it . check it out

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Comment: Rishabh thanks but not the answer I was looking for. My specific query is why on my readded tab(using UndoManager that I implemented) tabsselect event is not firing and I am not able to select that particular tab. :(

Comment: @neena just check out the code I have sent above it will for sure solve your tab removal problem